# Use of escape sequence in sed command

Tags: sed

I want to replace `;` by `TERMINATED BY '\034' STORED AS TEXTFILE;`

I am using `sed` command but its replacing `\0` by `;`

```
sed "s|;|TERMINATED BY '\034' STORED AS TEXTFILE|"
```

I tried `\\034` but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed "s|;|TERMINATED BY '\\\034' STORED AS TEXTFILE|"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` solution is okay, [q operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) is helpful in such cases

```
$ echo 'abc ; xyz' | perl -pe "s/;/q(TERMINATED BY '\034' STORED AS TEXTFILE)/e"
abc TERMINATED BY '\034' STORED AS TEXTFILE xyz
```